# ORDER BY 2 parameters PDO

Tags: mysql

I want to make it order on `message_date` and `message_time`.
Now if i use;

```
    $message_show = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever=? ORDER BY message_date");
    $message_show->bindParam(1, $id);
    $message_show->execute();
```

This wil order on the date, but now i want to use a second parameter `message_time` to order it depend on the date and time, how to do this ?

**UPDAE**

---

Sorry forgot to add, i want the message_time output reverse so the newest time must come first.
Example;
Message time1: 09:30 and Message time 2: 09:31.

Now it gives 09.30 first i want the 09:31 first because thats the newest input.

Comment: `ORDER BY column1[, column2[, ...]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply add a second attribute to the `SELECT` statement

```
$message_show = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever=? ORDER BY message_date ASC, message_time ASC");
```

I do not believe it to be more complicated than this.

Comment: Thanks, so ASC reverse it and DESC do alphabetic. Learned something new today! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it as comma separated,

```
 $message_show = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever=? ORDER BY message_date, message_time");
```

*[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)*